# Removing duplicate values from StringBuffer

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I have a StringBuffer which contains duplicates value like the one shown on the left hand side of the example and want to convert it to the one showm on right. Two cases are shown below

```
{1,1,1,2,2,} to `{1,2}`
```

`{a,a,a,b,c,c,c,}` to `{a,b,c}`

Please also note that the content and size of StringBuffer is not fixed. I want to solve this problem just by string manipulation.

Comment: You could play around with `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` to accomplish this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The problem with doing so is the index can be anything. The size is not predetermined.

Comment: ... no there is no problem with that... look at the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Are you talking about removing duplicate characters from the backing array, or are you interested in String manipulation?

Comment: I want String Manipulation in this case.

Comment: Do you want to remove all duplicates, or just adjacent ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here's a solution that works for duplicates that are **not** adjacent. It is a bit clunky though...

```
//Deletes all extra occurrences of String x(which can just be a single character)
public static StringBuffer removeDuplicateOf(StringBuffer s, String x){
    while(s.indexOf(x) != s.lastIndexOf(x))
        s.deleteCharAt(s.lastIndexOf(x));
    return s;
}
```

Note, if you didn't know which items were duplicated, you'd have to call this on every item in your StringBuffer. (Well once per *unique* item in your StringBuffer.)

For example you could do:

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("1,2,4,8,16,1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,");
s.removeDuplicateOf(s, "1,");
```

This would avoid removing the "1" from "16", "10", etc. while still removing the other occurence of "1".

Answer (score -2):

```
String s = "1,1,1,2,2";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1"));
```

Comment: This will remove duplicates that are *next to each other*. But if OP wants to remove all duplicates it won't do that.

Comment: Exactly, only works with duplicates next to each other. Even comma separation will prevent the replacement.

Comment: You may want to use something like this `s.replaceAll("(.*?,)\\1+", "$1")`. But even this works only if the duplicate numbers are adjacent to each other like in the question.